# How can I format data bars based on value in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, conditional-formatting

I have a dataset containing values from 0 to 584. I would like to illustrate this using data bars, but I would like the databars to be green when the number is greater than 150, and red when the number is equal or less than 150.

Consider:

[image]

The green bars illustrate the relative values, but I cannot get RED bars on the chart concurrently.

Further consider:

[image]

This is what happens when I apply the rule for red to appear if the value is less than or equal to 150. It appears that the red bar illustates relative values from 0 to 150...not 0 to 584.

Is there a way to combine these two rules? Ideally, I would have a data bar for each number that would show it's relative value, but SOME would be green and SOME would be red, based on being > < 150.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only apply one data bar rule to a set of cells. You can, however combine data bars and a conditional cell fill based on a formula like

=A1<=150

This will highlight the whole cell, though.
[image]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. That was my initial strategy, but I hated the way it looked. :) C'est la vie...thanks for confirmation that I should stop looking for a way to do this. Awesome Excel site by the way...I've got your site bookmarked; I know I'll need some of those chart tips eventually.

Answer (score 0):

A limit I never liked about data bars was that they are monochrome – one colour for positive values, one colour for negative. So a couple of weeks ago I sat down to figure out a workaround. If anyone’s interested…
http://digimac.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/multicoloured-data-bars-in-excel/

Comment: I found out it didn't work except on my PC - a matter of my rather unique language settings which mix English, Italian and German.
:-(
Fixed and expanded and released as standard AddIn.
http://digimac.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/multicoloured-databars-excel-addin/
Please try it and tell me what you think